# Input Vs process rows is showing as 0 in pyspark stream writer?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Data frame is having data,but when it is writing to delta table the stream writer is not writing any data

[image]

Comment: are you really have new data coming? input rate is 0

Comment: 1.We have list of the josn files available in the path.2.Using stream reader need to read all the files from the path and write it to a delta table.3.But streamwriter is contionously running but records are not inserting into the delta table.Can you please do the needful

Comment: 1.Start a stream from the path --->List of the json files avilable in this path
2.Write the stream to a Delta table.:
The table's format should be "delta"

This table already exists in the datbase we need to append the existing delta data.

Comment: data_df = (
      spark.readStream.schema(json_Schema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1).json(path)
    )

data_df.writeStream.format("delta"). \
                   outputMode("append"). \
                   option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path). \
                   table("orders")

Comment: how do you read that stream? post the whole code, but not as screenshot

Comment: data_df = (
      spark.readStream.schema(json_Schema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1).json(path)
    )

data_df.writeStream.format("delta"). \
                   outputMode("append"). \
                   option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path). \
                   table("orders")